# Android crash: Failed to initialize display event receiver

Tags: android, crash

my application crashed when I start it again after closing it for quite some time. Below you can see the log that shows the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize display event receiver. status=-2147483648
at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.nativeInit(Native Method)
at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.<init>(DisplayEventReceiver.java:61)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.<init>(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.<init>(Choreographer.java:169)
at android.view.Choreographer.<init>(Choreographer.java:69)
at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:95)
at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:88)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:430)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
at android.view.Choreographer.getInstance(Choreographer.java:194)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:487)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:235)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm looking for the solution or at least someone with similar problem but surprisingly there is none.
Someone can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this error specific for some smartphone model or emulator? Or it happens in different devices?

Comment: You should also post code where this error is being occurred. Maybe then we can help.

Comment: This error is occurred on Galaxy s4 mini, galaxy nexus and galaxy s3. In crash report there isn't reference of my application code.

Comment: @Adri , do you find the solution? I also meet this issue, and have no clue. Anyone who can help will be appreciated.